# "in" vs "of" vs "at"

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I'm having a hard time to comprehend the difference between the three prepositions "of"&"in"&"at" in a lot of occasions.The below is an example of that,so which sentence is idiomatic and why ??

1- My first attempt of making a pancake.

2- My first attempt in making a pancake.

1- My first attempt at making a pancake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third one is grammatical since "attempt" is being used as a noun and the following verb is not infinitive

"Attempt", when used as a noun, is usually followed by "at".

> This is an attempt at making a pancake

But when the verb that follows is infinitive, you use "to".

> This is an attempt to make a pancake

When "Attempt" is used as a verb, it is always followed by "to" and an infinitive verb.

> I am attempting to make a pancake

Comment: @Thank you for the useful info, but don't you think that "of" which means "concerning" could work  (This is an attempt of making a pancake )

Comment: "Attempt" always goes with "at" or "to". "of" and 'by" can be used in the context "An attempt by/of Mohamed at making/ to make" but not directly before the verb.

Comment: Thank a lot for the great explanation.